# Playwright mock route with search params

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm trying to mock a route with a search params

The route is like : http://localhost:8080/city?zip=1234

I tried this :

```
 await page.route('*/**/city/*', async route => {
    await route.fulfill({ status: 200, json: [] });
  });
```

But it's not catching the status or the response (got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Answer (score 0):

There's no slash after `city`, so `city/*` is off the table. Something like `**/city?*` or `*/*/*/city?*` should work:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.41.2

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script>
(async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/city?zip=1234");
  console.log(res.status, JSON.stringify(await res.json()));
})();
</script></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const consoleLogged = page.waitForEvent("console");
  await page.route("*/*/*/city?*", async route => {
    await route.fulfill({ status: 200, json: ["testing"] });
  });
  await page.setContent(html);
  console.log(await consoleLogged); // => 200 ["testing"]
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Or in a test format:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.41.2

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script>
(async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/city?zip=1234");
  document.body.textContent = (await res.json())[0];
})();
</script></body></html>`;

test("/city? is intercepted", async ({page}) => {
  await page.route("*/*/*/city?*", async route => {
    await route.fulfill({ status: 200, json: ["testing"] });
  });
  await page.setContent(html);
  await expect(page.locator("body")).toHaveText("testing");
});
```

If you want to be more precise, `"**/city?zip=*"` or the regex `/\/city\?zip=\d+$/` are also possible.